# @font-face not working on chrome but works on other browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want one simple thing...my font to work on chrome.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "Iosevka";
    src: url("http://www.some_url/iosevka-regular.woff2") format(woff2),
         url('http://www.some_url/iosevka-regular.otf') format(opentype),
         url('http://www.some_url/iosevka-regular.ttf') format(truetype);
         url('http://www.some_url/iosevka-regular.eot) format(embedded-opentype);
}
```

This works on safari and firefox but not chrome. I am not exactly sure why

I have looked at several posts saying I need to add more font support so I have ttf, woff2, eot, and otf but this still doesn't work.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Edge supports OTF and TTF, if you don't need IE support; Microsoft is at end of support for IE on June 15. I would take the last line out ... the ; on 2nd to last may be causing the problem. If you need IE or EOT support ... I would create a separate rule just for IE.

Comment: I'm not certain of the best policy for which rule first on the two rule method ... I've ended internet explorer support.

Comment: I have removed the last line and fixed the ; on the 2nd to last line however it is still not working

Comment: The last line should have the ; sorry if i was not clear, ... two ";" within the rule was suspect.

Comment: I see, even with the semi-colon just at the end it still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Not working means? Newer broswers don't request the font until they see the need for it.  what is the CSS where you are using the font?

Comment: I am not sure what that means? I am just adding ```@font-face``` to the beginning of my html. By not working I mean I refresh the page and the font doesn't change

Comment: K, I posted an answer, so you can compare. You need the rule for the tag you will use the font, and you need the tag on the page ... and someplaces you need to use "" others you don't use the ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest supported loading of a font on the web today. Only need one font file and it needs to be used.

Two CSS rules and a HTML tag.

Microsoft was the holdout for TTF although they were part of building the TTF. All systems have the license to use TTF and caniuse reports all browsers supporting it.

Note this does not mean you can use anybodies licenced font. It means you can use TTF to display the font.

OTF is open license so no license is required and supported by all systems including Microsoft edge.

Not sure of the status of Woff and SVG is not supported by Chrome.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Logo";
  src: url("/fonts/logo.ttf"); /* or url("/fonts/logo.otf") */
  }
.logo {
  font-family: Logo;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: normal;
  }

<h1 class="logo">
```

Browsers don't download the font until they need to use the font. But the font can be downloaded with Javascript if one does not like the normal behavior.

Comment: I have implemented your solution however it still does not work. sadness.

Comment: Do you have access to the logs? Under dev tools console is the font URL location working? Can you put the font on your server?

Comment: I have access to the logs however apache says there are no "errors". I have moved the fonts to the ```/fonts/``` directory so the location should be correct.

Comment: If it makes any difference at all the html is inside of a php folder

Comment: If the HTML is getting to the browser it will work even if the CSS is not in the head section of the HTML. Although it is best practice to have the CSS in the head section and in a CSS file as humans trying to debug need to find it.

Comment: I don't think this is an incorrect syntax problem. I've been at this for several hours now and nothing works. I am going to try another font but I doubt it will make any difference. I have moved everything to a css file for good measure but like I said it didn't make a difference.

Comment: YES! Just got it working. Thank you for your help! Just needed a little more tweaking